# A more "pythonic" approach to "check for None and deal with it"

Tags: string, coding-style, python

I have a `list` of `dict` with keys `['name','content','summary',...]`. All the values are strings. But some values are `None`. I need to remove all the new lines in `content`, `summary` and some other keys. So, I do this:

```
...
...
for item in item_list:
    name = item['name']
    content = item['content']
    if content is not None: content = content.replace('\n','')
    summary = item['summary']
    if summary is not None: summary = summary.replace('\n','')
    ...
    ...
...
...
```

I somewhat feel that the `if x is not None: x = x.replace('\n','')` idiom not so intelligent or clean. Is there a more "pythonic" or better way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Absence of a key in a dictionary encodes "nothing here" as well or better than None.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are going to use sentinel values (None) then you will be burdened with checking for them.

There are a lot of different answers to your question, but they seem to be missing this point: don't use sentinel values in a dictionary when the absence of an entry encodes the same information.

For example:

```
bibliography = [
    { 'name': 'bdhar', 'summary': 'questioner' },
    { 'name': 'msw', 'content': 'an answer' },
]
```

then you can

```
for article in bibliography:
    for key in article:
        ...
```

and then your loop is nicely ignorant of what keys, if any, are contained in a given article.

In reading your comments, you claim that you are getting the dict from somewhere else. So clean it of junk values first. It is *much* more clear to have a cleaning step then it is to carry their misunderstanding through your code.

Comment: I actually think this is the best answer here: it discusses a much more pythonic way of dealing with things.

Comment: @msw: Thanks. yes, i should better clean the values first. it would make more sense.

Answer (score 7):

The code feels unwieldy to you, but part of the reason is because you are repeating yourself. This is better:

```
def remove_newlines(text):
    if text is not None:
        return text.replace('\n', '')

for item in item_list:
    name = item['name']
    content = remove_newlines(item['content'])
    summary = remove_newlines(item['summary'])
```

Answer (score 5):

Python has a [ternary operator](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions), so one option is to do this in a more natural word order:

```
content = content.replace('\n', '') if content is not None else None
```

Note that if `""` and `None` are equivalent in your case (which appears to be so), you can shorten it to just `if content`, as non-empty strings evaluate to `True`.

```
content = content.replace('\n', '') if content else None
```

This also follows the Python idiom of *explicit is better than implicit*. This shows someone following the code that the value can be `None` very clearly.

It's worth noting that if you repeat this operation a lot, it might be worth encapsulating it as a function.

Another idiom in Python is *ask for forgiveness, not permission*. So you could simply use `try` and `except` the `AttributeError` that follows, however, this becomes a lot more verbose in this case, so it's probably not worth it, especially as the cost of the check is so small.

```
try:
    content = content.replace('\n', '')
except AttributeError:
    content = None
    #pass #Also an option, but as mentioned above, explicit is generally clearer than implicit.
```

Comment: While you are on the point of exception handling, it is noteworthy that `try` is cheap, but `except` is relatively expensive.

Comment: @MatthewSchinckel The presumption is that where you are catching an exception it is a rare case. If that isn't so, then yes, the cost of the `except` can be an issue.

Comment: It is worth noting that many consider the ternary operator unPythonic despite being in the language http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/python-ternary-operator Even http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/ has an air of resignation about it.

Comment: @Lattyware yes, that's a nice way to put it.

Comment: @msw I must say I really don't agree - I think that it's much nicer than trying to cram an `if` statement onto one line.

Comment: There are certainly reasonable arguments for both sides as was captured in that SO link. I agree that the one-line `if` makes for confusing reading. (my comment was just a comment, if I'd meant "-1" I would have said so)

Comment: @msw Of course, I didn't take offence - it's a perfectly valid comment, and I was unaware of the disagreement surrounding the ternary operator, I was just saying I like the way it writes/reads.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to use the empty string instead of None.  This is not a fully general solution, but in many cases if your data is all of a single type, there will be a sensible "null" value other than None (empty string, empty list, zero, etc.).  In this case it looks like you could use the empty string.

Comment: Yes. But I get the `dict` from somewhere else. I am not populating it with values.

Comment: @bdhar - if you're doing much processing on the `dict` after you get it, I'd convert it to a more sensible form anyway.

Comment: @weronika: yes, i should consider that perhaps.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
if content: content = content.replace('\n','')
```

--

`if content` will (almost<sup>1</sup>) always be `True` as long as `content` contains anything except for 0, False, or None.

---

<sup>1</sup>As Lattyware correctly points out in the comments, this is not strictly True. There are other things that will evaluate to `False` in an `if` statement, for example, an empty list. See the link provided in the comment below.

Comment: Your final line isn't technically true. Empty containers also evaluate to `False`, as can anything defining `__nonzero__()` in 2.x or `__bool__()` in 3.x, and some other things. [The docs explain in full](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing).

Answer (score 2):

The empty string evaluates to False in Python, so the Pythonic way is `if content:`.

```
In [2]: bool("")
Out[2]: False

In [3]: bool("hello")
Out[3]: True
```

---

Side note but you can make your code a little clearer:

```
name, content = item["name"], item["content"]
```

And:

```
content = content.replace('\n','') if content else None
```

Answer (score 2):

You might also consider abstracting some of your if clauses into a separate function:

```
def remove_newlines(mystr):
    if mystr:
        mystr = mystr.replace('\n')
    return mystr
```

(edited to remove the over-complicated solution with dictionaries, etc)

Comment: I feel this is a bit of an over-engineered solution. Unless you do this a lot throughout your code, I would just use the `remove_newlines()` function and call it there.

Comment: @Lattyware that's a reasonable critique.  What do you think about the second version (just updated it)?

Comment: The `identity` function caused me to have to read it twice to see that it really was a NOP. I second "over-engineered".

Comment: I changed the post to just focus on the remove_newlines function and leave everything else out.  Thanks for the commentary @msw and Lattyware

Answer (score 1):

I think that the "pythonic" thing is to use the fact that None will evaluate to False in an if statement.
So you can just say:

```
if content: content = content.replace('\n','')
```